# How can I find exactly which files have been accessed after a command runs in tcsh?

Tags: path, tcsh, locate

how can I find which files `tcsh` reads to `TAB` complete the second word of a command, as opposed to the first word.

I know I can just use `whereis complete` to see the path to `*.1.gz` file, but that is not specific enough to say which files are being used.

On the other hand, if I use `locate complete`, I am given a list of a couple hundred files, many of which aren't executable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use **`strace`** to capture the whole session, and pick up the keyboard-read by browsing the script output, and then find all of the open-calls after that.  That works with Linux and some other systems. There's a similar trace for BSD's (MacOS is a different story though).

However, tcsh likely is not ***opening*** the files but listing them from the directory.  strace would help with that, too.  For instance, in a quick check I see it opening the current directory using [**`openat`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/openat.html)

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

and then using the [**`lstat`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lstat.html) function to determine what the entries of interest are (so that it can sort them, decide which are files versus directories, etc):

```
lstat("xterm.desktop", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=1921, ...}) = 0
```

The ***"."*** is the current directory. The program reads a list of directory entries which may be files, directories, symbolic links, etc., but those are not sorted (and types are unknown, until it uses **`stat`**/**`lstat`** to ask).

**`locate`** and **`whereis`** won't show useful data, since they do not use the same rules for finding the files as **`tcsh`**.

Comment: Okay, so I found the spot in strace when tab completed the word. I typed echot and it was completed to echotc. However, I cannot discern what files were accessed in the process. The only open command that I see inbetween is " openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 ".

Comment: st_mode is just telling me the file type and mode? Can I get further information on which files were actually consulted to excute TAB complete properly, after tcsh used lstat?

Comment: You could read tcsh's source-code.  Offhand, the reason why it does the lstat's is to determine which entries it can show.  Assume it showed all of those for which the lstat was performed.